# Debug Failure. Unhandled SyntaxKind: ImportClause

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, docker, webpack

I'm trying to build a React app using Webpack inside Docker container.

Running the command `webpack --mode production --progress --config webpack.prod.js` ends up with the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/App.tsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: Debug Failure. Unhandled SyntaxKind: ImportClause.
    at pipelineEmitWithHintWorker (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:114180:22)
    at pipelineEmitWithHint (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113711:17)
    at pipelineEmitWithSourceMaps (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:117731:13)
    at pipelineEmitWithComments (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:117399:13)
    at pipelineEmit (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113651:13)
    at emitExpression (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113635:13)
    at emitImportDeclaration (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:115606:13)
    at pipelineEmitWithHintWorker (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113912:32)
    at pipelineEmitWithHint (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113711:17)
    at pipelineEmitWithSourceMaps (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:117731:13)
 @ ./src/index.tsx 5:0-36 13:36-39
```

Running the same command to build on host machine (MacOS) works as expected.
The container runs on `node:16.13.1-alpine` official image.

Comment: Could you share your Dockerfile contents and webpack.config.js contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems most likely the error is caused by bug in Webpack or one of its dependencies. Just because you are able to build your app successfully on your host machine, but not working in Docker.

One thing you can try is to update Webpack and all of its dependencies to the latest versions. If it doesn't fix problem, you can try downgrading to an older version of Webpack.

If you are still can not resolve issue, you can try reporting it to Webpack maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

The error is TypeScript specific error, this only points to one thing that you might have latest typescript installed on your dev machine. And your own docker builder in your own machine might use latest typescript.

But Docker (If installed with Docker Desktop), actually installs a Linux VM and Docker runs inside the VM. The BuildX might be installing older version of typescript and which would be giving this error.

If you manually install `npm install typescript`, it will install latest typescript in your dev machine, but if your package.json contains reference to old typescript version, `npm install` inside docker file, will install old typescript package.

Before your webpack, try manually installing latest typescript version.

`RUN npm install -g typescript@5.2.0`

And then run your webpack command.